# linearHypothesis function in R and interaction terms

Tags: hypothesis-testing, interaction

I'm running the model:

`model <- lm(y~ index1*gender +education, data=data)`

and trying to test the null that the effect of index1 on y is 0 when gender=1 and am wondering if the following is the correct way to think about setting up this linear combination:

`linearHypothesis(model, c('index1 + index1*gender = 0'))`

Comment: An asterisk can be used to indicate both the main effects and the corresponding interaction term in an R `formula`, but it can't be used for `car`'s `linearHypothesis`. Use a colon instead: `"index1 + index1:gender = 0"`.

Comment: Thanks @DaeyoungLim. Does this setup depend on whether the model has other controls, interactions, etc.? For example, the full model is: `model <- lm(y~ index1*gender +education + index2*gender, data=data)`

Comment: That won’t matter. Interactions should be specified with colons